# how to make text clickable in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, jython-2.7

How to make text clickable ?

```
class ComplainceServer():
    def __init__(self, jira_server, username, password, encoding='utf-8'):
        if jira_server is None:
            error('No server provided.')

        #print(jira_server)
        self.jira_server = jira_server
        self.username = username
        self.password = password
        self.encoding = encoding

    def checkComplaince(self, appid, toAddress):

        query = "/rest/api/2/search?jql=issuetype = \"Application Security\" AND \"Prod Due Date\" < now()
        request = self._createRequest()
        response = request.get(query, contentType='application/json')
        # Parse result
        if response.status == 200 and action == "warn":
            data = Json.loads(response.response)
            print "#### Issues found"
            issues = {}
            msg = "WARNING: The below tickets are non-complaint in fortify, please fix them or raise exception.\n"
            issue1 = data['issues'][0]['key']
            for item in data['issues']:
                issue = item['key']
                issues[issue] = item['fields']['summary']
                print u"* {0} - {1}".format(self._link(issue), item['fields']['summary'])
                print "\n"
                data = u" {0}  -  {1}".format(self._link(issue), item['fields']['summary'])

                msg += '\n'+ data
            SOCKET_TIMEOUT = 30000 # 30s
            email = SimpleEmail()
            email.setHostName('smtp.com')
            email.setSmtpPort(25)
            email.setSocketConnectionTimeout(SOCKET_TIMEOUT);
            email.setSocketTimeout(SOCKET_TIMEOUT);

            email.setFrom('R@group.com')
            for toAddress in toAddress.split(','):
                email.addTo(toAddress)
            email.setSubject('complaince report')
            email.addHeader('X-Priority', '1')
            email.setMsg(str(msg))
            email.send()

    def _createRequest(self):
        return HttpRequest(self.jira_server, self.username, self.password)

    def _link(self, issue):
        return '[{0}]({1}/browse/{0})'.format(issue, self.jira_server['url'])
```

This is the calling function. APPid and toAddress will be passed in from different UI.

```
from Complaince import ComplainceServer

jira = ComplainceServer(jiraServer, username, password)

issues = jira.checkComplaince(appid, toAddress)
```

I want issueid to be an embedded link.

currently the email sends as below:

```
MT-4353(https://check.com/login/browse/MT-4353) - Site Sc: DM isg_cq5
```

but i want `[MT-4353]` as hyperlink to the URL `https://check.com/login/browse/MT-4353`

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you need to encode your email as html.  I'm not familiar with the library you are using so I cannot give an example of this.

I have replaced a snippet of your code with html syntax just to illustrate the point that you are meant to use html syntax to have clickable links in an email.

```
            msg = "<p>WARNING: The below tickets are non-compliant in fortify, please fix them or raise exception.</p>"
            issue1 = data['issues'][0]['key']
            for item in data['issues']:
                issue = item['key']
                issues[issue] = item['fields']['summary']
                data = u"<a href='{0}'>{1}</a>".format(self._link(issue), item['fields']['summary'])
                msg += '<br />'+ data
```

In future, please ask your questions carefully as your title does not question does not indicate what you are actually meaning.  You also have spelling mistakes: Compl**ia**nt

Oh, I missed the point of `self._link(issue)` not returning the correct link.  It returns `MT-4353(https://check.com/login/browse/MT-4353)` so you are going to need to extract the link part between the brackets.  I suggest a regular expression.

Comment: Sorry, will properly format the question, but it is still taking it as normal text. here is the output i see now:      <p>Blocker: The below tickets are non-compliant in fortify</p><br /><a href='check.com/login/browse/MT-3195'>MT-3195</a> - Weak Encryption<br /><a href='https://check.com/login/browse/MT-3196'>MT-3196</a> - Weak Encryption<br />

Comment: Here is the code looks like now :    msg = "<p>\nBlocker: The below tickets are non-compliant in fortify\n</p>"
issue1 = data['issues'][0]['key']
for item in data['issues']:
    issue = item['key']
    issues[issue] = item['fields']['summary']
    print u"* {0} - {1}".format(self._link(issue), item['fields']['summary'])
    print "\n"
    linking = "https://check.com/login/browse/" + str(issue)
    data = u"<a href='{0}'>{1}</a> - {2}".format(linking, issue, item['fields']['summary'])
    msg += '<br />' + data

Comment: Ok, so now you need to find a method on your SimpleEmail instance that will set your body as being html content.  From what module are you importing SimpleEmail from?

Comment: from org.apache.commons.mail import EmailException, SimpleEmail, HtmlEmail                 this is the import statement which is from this : https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-email/

Comment: public Email setMsg(String msg) throws EmailException {
        if (EmailUtils.isEmpty(msg)) {
            throw new EmailException("Invalid message supplied");
        } else {
            this.setTextMsg(msg);
            StringBuffer htmlMsgBuf = new StringBuffer(msg.length() + "<html><body><pre>".length() + "</pre></body></html>".length());
            htmlMsgBuf.append("<html><body><pre>").append(msg).append("</pre></body></html>");
            this.setHtmlMsg(htmlMsgBuf.toString());
            return this;
        }
    }

Comment: http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/commons/proper/email/trunk/src/main/java/org/apache/commons/mail/